# How can I automatically mute the volume at every boot?

Tags: sound, default

Sometimes I forget to enable mute before shutting down my laptop.

Can I set it up to be muted by default every time Ubuntu boots, before the login screen is displayed?

---

When I try DoR's suggestion of `sudo alsactl store`, the settings stored in `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` are lost on the next reboot. Something is using this file to automatically save the current volume settings every time I reboot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this needs two parts:

1. To mute the sound in GDM, put:

   ```
   amixer sset Master 0
   amixer sset Master off
   ```

   in the file `/etc/rc.local` (make sure `exit 0` is the last line in that file). This will set the volume level to 0 on the Master channel and mute it.
2. To mute the sound in your session, add the above to the startup applications:

   *System > Preferences > Startup Applications*, then click on *Add* and create the new startup entry:

   - Name: `Mute Sound`
   - Command: `/bin/bash -c "amixer sset Master 0 ; amixer sset Master off"`
   - Comment: `Set Master channel volume to 0 and mute it`

   Click on *Add* and *Close*, and you should be done.

You can skip part one, if you turn off the login sound in *System > Administration > Login Screen* (untick the *Play login sound* checkbox).

Comment: are you sure about the command given? 

It didn't seem to work for me.

I went the long way round and made a script with the commands you mentioned and then pointed to it using the Browse button. Essentially the same thing...would it be because I'm using Netbook Edition? 

I'm having some weird and wonderful problems with UNE...

Comment: Not working in 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Mute the volume and then run the following command:

```
sudo alsactl store
```

This will store your current sound settings, so from now on the sound will be muted on startup. I tested this out and it mutes both the [GDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) sound and the login sound.

Comment: This is promising, but the stored settings appear to revert every time I reboot. I've included a screenshot above.

Comment: I have the same issue. The sound settings revert on rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

This need to be addressed in 'Upstart', which has taken over from using 'sudo alsactl store' or similar.

( I will report back, on what I find. )