# How can I find out which programs have modified a file over some period of time?

Tags: troubleshooting, files, process, logging

I'd like to better understand which programs are modifying a specific file<sup>1</sup> during a reboot. Can I set something up to log this kind of information?

Polling for which processes *currently* have the file open won't work, as the file may only be open for a few milliseconds.

Can kernel tracing be used to collect this information?

---

<sup>1</sup> [`/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24208/how-can-i-automatically-mute-the-volume-at-every-boot) if you're curious, but I'm interested in a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the `fuser` tool.  It lists the process ID of all processes accessing a specific file.  Try,

```
fuser -u .
```

...to see which files are "open" in your home directory, the process ID's involved and the username owning those processes.

In your case, I'm not sure this will be useful since you're trying to monitor a reboot.  I suspect that rc.local will execute too late in the reboot to capture anything useful with, say,

`watch -n 0.5 "fuser -u /var/lib/alsa/asound.state"`

Hmm - I've just tried dumping this to a file and the output isn't very pretty.  But if this can be resolved, then perhaps something can be achieved with cron?

Comment: `lsof` is another tool that might be useful, if it is wrapped in something.

Comment: Not come across that, but you're right - lsof has better output actually!  It lists the name of the process, the user, the PID, the name of the file and more.

Comment: I don't think `-f` does anything. ([Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/fuser.1.html))

Comment: I would keep the- f to make this command more interesting to read aloud.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the man pages, both `fuser` and `lsof` can only report what is occurring at a given instant. For all I know, however, the file may only remain open for a fraction of a second. How frequently would I need to poll with these tools to be sure not to miss the file being opened?

Comment: I've removed the -f (the man page states that it's silently ignored anyway).  ændrük, I have no idea how to capture the information that fast.  I find the output from tailing the `watch` command pretty difficult to read anyway, so running it with say `-n .1` will be even uglier.  I think another solution may be required.  Sorry.