# How to boot muted?

Tags: sound, boot

How can we boot muted as sometimes booting and start up sounds will disturb people around in a silent environment (*libraries etc.*)?

I know I can remove the start up sound effects but that's not I want.

Comment: What are you looking for then? That your sound is always mute every boot? A possibility to disable it at login screen?

Comment: Related: [How can I automatically mute the volume at every boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24208/how-can-i-automatically-mute-the-volume-at-every-boot)

Comment: I want to boot my pc in a muted state. How this can be confusing =)

Comment: 11.10 Ubuntu???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automatically mute the volume at every boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24208/how-can-i-automatically-mute-the-volume-at-every-boot)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 11.10 you can mute your system sound before logging in to you system. Just click the sound icon and mute it.

[image]

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that the drum sound has already been emitted before you even have the chance to mute it.

Answer (score -2):

Click shut-down icon on your indicator and select **Startup Applications**, higlight **GNOME Longin Sound** and click remove.

Comment: fastreload didn't want to do that.

Comment: Goto System choose  Administration and select Login Screen. Click Unlock and Uncheck  Play Login Sound and  close.

Comment: Or simply copy and paste at Terminal: sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/sound/event

Comment: Please read the question carefully: *"I know I can remove the start up sound effects but that's _not_ I want."*

Comment: Please, explain better because I can't see anything beyond booting without login sound in your question.If what you wanted to do is to mute the sound in your system, then you can use the Banshee Sound Setting to do that by click mute and it will also mute the system sound while logging in. I hope that is what you want. Thank you