# Why is sound changed muted on 11.10 startup?

Tags: 11.10, sound, laptop, mute

Sound is always muted at startup that is after the login. I have to unmute it every time. How can i fix this sound mute problem which occurs at the startup? BTW, I am using HP Mini.

Comment: possible duplicate

Comment: This seems different, since it's easy to un-mute the sound. But it still shouldn't start muted. I have this problem too, albeit only sporadically (and generally only after a full restart), even when I log off/shut down and the sound is at some other level.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been much discussed in:

[No sound after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24722/no-sound-after-boot)

[How can I automatically mute the volume at every boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24208/how-can-i-automatically-mute-the-volume-at-every-boot)

(Which are really the same subject.)

Comment: Those are for 11.04 and not 11.10. Things changed alot between the 2 ;)